# Always request becomes not found method on Sinatra and Unicorn and Nginx

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, unicorn

To be deployed in the Sinatra and Unicorn and nginx, when you access to the appropriate URL, will always request becomes "not_found do" method.

(For Example: hogehoge.com/test/)

But, When I have tested locally, it will enter to properly "get '/' do" method.

Do you think that somewhere there is a problem with?

Please tell me.

[test.rb]

```
# coding: utf-8
require "sinatra"
require 'unicorn'
class Main < Sinatra::Application
 get '/' do
  'Success'
 end

 not_found do
  'not_found'
 end
end
```

[config.ru]

```
require './test'
run Main
```

[unicorn.rb]

```
@dir = "/var/www/Test"
worker_processes 2
working_directory @dir
preload_app true
timeout 30
listen "#{@dir}/tmp/test.sock", :backlog => 64
pid "#{@dir}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{@dir}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{@dir}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
```

[nginx.conf]

```
location /test {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://Test;
        }

upstream Test {
       server unix:/var/www/Test/tmp/test.sock;
    }
```

Comment: I don't use Unicorn, but a quick read of their front page shows that's not the usual way of starting a process under it. Don't `require` it from `test.rb`; just run it from the command line with `unicorn -c unicorn.rb`. It also might be easier to test it *without* nginx first; so fire up unicorn on a port instead of a Unix socket and cURL it to see if your endpoint resolves correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

different nginx path & rb path

> (For Example: hogehoge.com/test/)

**[test.rb]**

```
# coding: utf-8
require "sinatra"
require 'unicorn'
class Main < Sinatra::Application
 get '/' do
  'Success'
 end

 get '/test' do
  'test Success'
 end

 not_found do
  'not_found'
 end
end
```

add

```
 get '/test' do
  'test Success'
 end
```

Comment: Greeeeeeeeeat! Thank you so much!